# Xcode build for iOS crashes after adding firebase to the flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, swiftui

The flutter app was working until adding firebase. Xcode build fails

```
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: static (extension in 
SwiftUI):SwiftUI.DynamicProperty._propertyBehaviors.getter : 
Swift.UInt32

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: method descriptor for static 
SwiftUI.DynamicProperty._propertyBehaviors.getter : Swift.UInt32

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: 
_swift_continuation_throwingResumeWithError

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _swift_continuation_await

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$sScC6resume8throwingyq_n_tF

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$sScC6resume9returningyxn_tF

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: 
_swift_async_extendedFramePointerFlags

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$ss31withCheckedThrowingContinuation8function_xSS_yScCyxs5Error_pGXEtYaKlFTu

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$ss31withCheckedThrowingContinuation8function_xSS_yScCyxs5Error_pGXEtYaKlF

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _swift_continuation_init

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _$sScCMn

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: 
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _swift_task_dealloc

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _swift_task_alloc

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: 
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibilityConcurrency

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _swift_continuation_throwingResume

Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: 
__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

**pubspec.yaml looks like this**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.0
  firebase_auth_web: ^3.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.0
```

**Podfile looks like this**

```
 # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '11.0'


 target 'Runner' do
   use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
   pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 
  'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', 
  :tag => '9.6.0'
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 end
```

Initially, app got struck at 'Running Xcode build'. later i added 'pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git =>' in the podFile but throws error.
I tried most of the solutions listed on the same build issue but still not working for me